# Executar um método main em um projeto web

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Estou usando o `Intellij` e estou com um projeto web e com o `Wildfly` já configurado nas opções `Run`. Eu criei uma classe com o método main para testes neste mesmo projeto e quero executar ela. Como posso fazer ? Sempre quando clico no Run o wildfly é `iniciado`.

```
public class Testes {

    public void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Teste");

    }
}
```

Comment: Tente `Shift + Alt + F10`

Comment: @nullptr ele abre um popup com o Wildfly e Edit Configurations.

Comment: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000156824-How-to-choose-main-class

Comment: @nullptr no meu não tem algumas opções ali :/